# Why doesn't globals work as I would expect when importing?

Tags: python, variables, scope

In the file `foo.py` I have this:

```
d = {}
d['x'] = 0
x = 0

def foo():
    global d
    global x
    d['x'] = 1
    x = 1
```

Then in an interpreter:

```
>>> from foo import *
>>> d['x']
0
>>> x
0
>>> foo()
>>> d['x']
1
>>> x
0
```

I expected this:

```
>>> x
1
```

What am I not understanding?

Comment: 99% of the time I advise against using `globals`.  99% of the time I advise against using `from foo import *`.  So, the chances of you needing to use them together drops down to about 0.01% ... (if my estimates are approximately correct).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The global namespace of `foo` is imported into your current namespace only once (when you do the `from foo import *`).  After that, if you change `foo`'s namespace, it won't be reflected in your current namespace.

Note that you can still change objects in `foo`'s namespace and see the changed in your current namespace.  That is why you see changes in `d`.  You still have a reference to the same object `d` that lives in `foo`'s namespace.

But, when you set:

```
x = 1
```

This *rebinds* a new object in the namespace of `foo`.

Comment: So the 'globals' referred to inside `foo` are really `foo.d` and `foo.x`, not `__main__.d` and `__main__.x` (although `__main__.d` and `foo.d` refer to the same object), and although `foo.x` now has the value 1, `__main__.x` is still 0.

Comment: @chepner -- nicely stated.

Comment: Thank you -- I was still trying to work out for myself how this works :)

Comment: @chepner -- if you think about module namespaces as dictionaries, and `from foo import *` as a `__main__.__dict__.update(foo.__dict__)` it becomes more clear.

Comment: Right; it is the behavior of the `global` keyword that I've never thought through carefully. The function saves a reference to the global namespace when it is defined (in `foo.func_globals`).

Answer (score 2):

Your `foo` module and the main module that imports it (named `__main__`) have separate namespaces.

Here's what happens:

1. Importing `foo` sets `foo`'s global variable `x` to refer to the integer object `0`.
2. This reference is copied into `__main__` as the global variable `x`.
3. You call `foo.foo()`, which sets `foo`'s global variable `x` to refer to the integer object `1`.
4. You print `__main__`'s global variable `x`. Because you never changed what this `x` refers to, it still refers to `0`, which is what is printed.

In short, importing a name into a module does not create any kind of binding between the names in the two modules. They initially refer to the same value, but if one name is re-bound to a different object, the other does not necessarily follow.

This is (one) reason why `import foo` is generally a better idea. Referring to `foo.x` explicitly in `__main__` refers exactly to `foo`'s global variable `x`, and will refer to the name's current value even if it has been changed.